# dynamically render strings as html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have input that may either be a string or be a string of html. I have figured out how to recognize whether or not the string is html, but I don't know how to have the browser interpret the string as html instead.

For example, instead of having `<a href='www.google.com'> Click here!! </a>` on the page, I would instead like to have the actual link render like: [Click Here](http://www.google.com)

View code where I am trying to do this:

```
<div class="description">    
  <%= p.description %>
<div>
```

Comment: could you paste your view code?

Comment: Sure, I added the line where I am trying to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mark the string as 'html safe' in one of two ways:

```
<%= raw @string %>
```

... or by explicitly marking the string as html_safe:

```
<%= @string.html_safe %>
```

However: Please bear in mind that if this input comes from untrusted users (i.e. anyone other than you!), then this could be a risky strategy, as it will allow cross site scripting attacks. Make sure you read the rails [security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss) for more information on this risk and how to effectively mitigate it.

Comment: very hard to choose between these two answers. both very informative and helpful. going with this one because of the security tips. I hadn't thought of that. Then again, I don't think of security as much as I should

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to use the [`raw` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw), if your code looks like this:

```
@your_bit_of_html = '<a href="www.google.com"> Click here!! </a>'
```

Then your view ERB should look like this:

```
<%= raw @your_bit_of_html %>
```

And, now that you've included a sample of your ERB:

```
<div class="description">    
  <%= raw p.description %>
<div>
```

Using `raw` assumes that you have properly encoded and cleansed any HTML that you're going to output so you'll need to exercise due caution.

Comment: The link to rubyonrails.org is not valid anymore.

Comment: @TrueSoft: Thanks, I updated it to match the current location of the `raw` helper.